# Finding a number in text always gives an error

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have text datatype in a table column `[Items]`, which always ends in a number:

```
Item 1
Item 3
```

Using a `find` formula in a calculated column works if I use text:

```
=FIND(" ",[Items])
```

But doesn't work if I use a number:

```
=FIND("1",[Items])
```

I have tried using `FORMAT(1,"string")`, tried looking for the number with and without quotes etc. I tried looking for `" 1"` with the space but nothing works if I include the number 1 in my formula.

Why not!? This type of behaviour isn't exhibited in Excel so makes it even more frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you need to pass an argument for what it should return when it doesn't find anything:

```
=FIND("1",[items],1,-1)
```

Comment: Thanks! This did work - I had assumed like Excel that `#ERROR` would only show up on specific rows where the `"1"` could not be found, particlularly because `StartPosition` and `NotFoundValue` are optional in `FIND` - But actually if *ANY* row throws an error, the entire column errors, which is why I couldn't see where it was going wrong. I guess that's because it's more of a SQL engine than a spreadsheet?